# Adding and Align JLabels and JCheckBoxes to a JScrollPane dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager

My starting point is this:

[image]

The rectangle under the labels is a `JScrollPane`.

Depending on the value of a variable I have to add JLabels and JCheckBoxes to the scrollpane.

I read other threads but I can't do what I want.
Can you help me?

I have no code because I thought that I could do it with the NetBeans designer.
The only thing that I can do is

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("New Label");
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("New CheckBox");
jScrollPane1.add(label);
jScrollPane1.add(cb);
```

but obviously it doesn't work.
Thanks to Robby now I can add components.
I need to know how to align them.
For example a column of labels under the jLabel1, a column of checkboxes under the jLabel2 etc.. all with the same height and width.

Comment: I hoped that NetBeans could generate all the code.
There is the "initComponents()" method that creates the JDialog in the image.

Comment: And when NetBeans failed to generate the code, you thought ... perhaps the people at stackoverflow would generate the code for me. I suggest to put some more effort in your question if you want answers, and not adding those components directly to the scrollpane but rather to another container which is contained in the scrollpane

Comment: You won't be able to build any decent application without learning and programming. Drag, point and click won't lead you further than a static screen doing nothing.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I will not work with swing anymore. I only needed to know how to dynamically add the components and how to align them.
With his answer, Roddy taught me the first part.
I don't need to build any decent application, only to align the components under the jlabels of the image in the scrollpane.

Answer (score 6):

You don't add elements directly to a JScrollPane. You add elements to a JPanel, that you *then* add to a JScrollPane. I strongly suggest reading up on Swing, if nothing else the [Java Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

So:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("New Label");
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("New CheckBox");
panel.add(label);
panel.add(cb);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Would be a start.

Or if the scroll pane already exists: `scrollPane.setViewportView(panel)` instead of the constructor.

Or similar. But really, as mentioned in above comments, you really want to learn to actually *code* first instead of relying on a program (or other people) to write code for you.